# How to trap System.exit() in code called from JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm writing a C interface to a java library that calls System.exit(). I call:

```
/* Calls the main method for the class */
printf("about to call main\n");
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, mainClass, mainMethod, args);
printf("returning from main\n");
```

I (unfortunately) don't have the option of changing the library, but I'd still like for the JVM to return control back to the C calling function (so I can do various cleanup tasks, etc..). Is there a way to get JNI to do that, or am I SOL?

Thanks,

Comment: Why is the pessimistic, incorrect answer still accepted?

Comment: because I don't have access to the source from the library to make the changes you suggest. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need bytecode editing for so simple case, a lot of security handling is implemented in the good old java.

`System.setSecurityManager(SecurityManager)` throw some Error (like ThreadDeath) in `checkExit()` and assuming `System.exit(int)` [erm `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(int)`] is invoked in the same thread, it should do it.

Comment: Sure enough. Righter than me.