# JNI CallStaticVoidMethod for main does not return to c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to trap System.exit() in code called from JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542853/how-to-trap-system-exit-in-code-called-from-jni)

`JNI CallStaticVoidMethod` after calling starts the `Java` process properly but does not return to `C++` code , it just exit after that.
My `java code` does not have have `system.exit(0)` but it just have `return;`

```
jclass StringClass = m_JVMEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    int numOfArguments = (int)m_ServerArguments.size() + 4 ;
    int argumentIndex = 0;

    jobjectArray jargs = m_JVMEnv->NewObjectArray(numOfArguments, StringClass, NULL);    

    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex++, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF("start"));

    std::string strJavaClassPath = "-classpath=";
    strJavaClassPath             += "\"";
    for ( std::size_t idx = 0; idx < m_listOfJars.size() - 1 ; idx++) {
        strJavaClassPath += m_ProductLibDir + "\\lib\\" + m_listOfJars[idx] + ";";
    }
    strJavaClassPath      += m_ProductLibDir + "\\lib\\" + m_listOfJars[m_listOfJars.size() - 1] ;
    strJavaClassPath      += "\"";

    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex++, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF(strJavaClassPath.c_str()));

    for ( std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = m_ServerArguments.begin(); iter != m_ServerArguments.end(); ++iter) {
        std::string argument = *iter;
        m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex++, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF(argument.c_str()));
    }
    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF("-dir=E:\\Avinash\\personal\\work\\CreateJvm\\Debug"));    

    m_JVMEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(m_CacheServerLauncherClass, m_MainMethodID, jargs);

    std::cout << "I am done with launching java program" << std::endl;
    m_RunningJVMInstance->DestroyJavaVM();
    CheckForJNIException();
```

`m_JVMEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(m_CacheServerLauncherClass, m_MainMethodID, jargs);` after this line program control does not return.

Comment: posting some code we can look at would be very helpful.  Not much we can suggest without it.

Comment: somehow this translates for me to "I called a function and that one called exit(0) and I wonder why that function does not return"

Comment: My java code is server which I just want to launch and then communicate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code is going to need a thread to run on, and if you want another thread for your C++ code you'll have to create one.