# System.exit in Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

My main thread created a new thread
And when the new thread call `System.exit(-1)`,my main thread be closed.
How can I handle the exit code and keep the main thread alive?

PS.
the new thread will call some method in other `.jar` file, so I can't modify it.

Comment: Does that method respond to interruptions? Do you have a way to make it exit?

Comment: Err, won't the termination of the JVM mean pretty much the end of everything? Regardless of interrupts?

Comment: @Thihara The question seems to be: how do I stop that thread without stopping the main thread. Of course System.exit will terminate the JVM, and it seems the OP understands that. But actually I can see that it can also be understood as: the new thread does call System.exit and I want to prevent it from doing so. This is unclear...

Comment: I would have said, use `return` in place of `System.exit(-1)`, but you say you can't modify the code. Not so easy!

Comment: @xagyg, `return` is usually a wrong choice as you do not know where the code might continue, you need some Exception/Error (e.g. ThreadDeath). yet bytecode instrumentation is not that hard and I'd probably do that. Last if you do not care too much about reverse engineering you can just extract the jar and either fix the bytecode once or decompile/edit/compiler; jar again.

Comment: @bestsss `return` is absolutely the correct choice when you want to leave/finish the thread. Your statement about "where the code might continue" is confusing. When the thread exits via return, the thread exits, it doesn't continue!

Comment: @xagyg, sure it is not, consider this `void run(){for(;;){ if (workDone()) cleanUpAndExit(); /*...some other stuff*/ } void cleanUpAndExits(){/*some cleanup*/; System.exit(-1);}` changing to return will do exactly nothing. The method can be deep in recursion/stack having loops and so one. I am not sure why you expect the invocation would be placed in run() method of the thread routine.

Comment: @bestsss Obviously it depends on the code and where you execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**the class:**

```
public class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm, Object context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkCreateClassLoader() {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkAccess(Thread t) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkAccess(ThreadGroup g) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new SecurityException("not allow to call System.exit");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkExec(String cmd) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkLink(String lib) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(FileDescriptor fd) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(String file) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(String file, Object context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkWrite(FileDescriptor fd) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkWrite(String file) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkDelete(String file) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkConnect(String host, int port) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkConnect(String host, int port, Object context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkListen(int port) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkAccept(String host, int port) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkMulticast(InetAddress maddr) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPropertiesAccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPropertyAccess(String key) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkTopLevelWindow(Object window) {
        return super.checkTopLevelWindow(window);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPrintJobAccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkSystemClipboardAccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkAwtEventQueueAccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPackageAccess(String pkg) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPackageDefinition(String pkg) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkSetFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkMemberAccess(Class<?> clazz, int which) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkSecurityAccess(String target) {
    }
}
```

**on startop:**

```
System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't.

`Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.`

That's the javadoc.

So the method will terminate the entire JVM. Not just the thread....

Comment: *You can't.* this is untrue, most of java security/OS sensitive code can be prevented via SecurityManager, it's a built in functionality since the very inception of java.

Comment: Oh yeah it slipped my mind... But only because I didn't knew about it... Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is vastly unclear, yet if the System.exit call succeeds the OS will terminate your application.

If you wish System.exit not to succeed you can install a Security manager and prevent that. Other than that you can instrument the code via custom classloader and remove the call.

Edit: if you go w/ Security manager, most likely throwing the SecurityException will terminate the thread. If it doesn't - cheat and throw a ThreadDeath. If that still doesn't - just hold the thread e.g. `for(;;) Thread.sleep(10000);` The latter will leak the thread and its resources but at least won't kill your application.

[link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542853/how-to-trap-system-exit-in-code-called-from-jni)

Comment: I think the `Security manager` can meet my needs,I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Java SecurityManager to save your main thread from exit and run the other thread code with the SecurityManager .

Edit:
Take idea from Tomcat or other server how they menage the code like `<% System.exit(1); %>` this in a JSPs.

Comment: You can not run *other threads* w/ security manager, it's global. You can detect threads within the manager but that's different.